# estimate performance gain based on application profiling (math)

Tags: performance

this question is rather "math" related - but certainly is of interest to any "software developer".

i have done some profiling of my application. and i have observed there is a huge performance difference that is "environment specific".
there is a "fast" environment and a "slow" environment.

- the `overall` application performance on "fast" is **5 times** faster than on "slow".
- a `particular` function call on "fast" is **18 times** faster than on "slow".

so let's *assume* i will be able to *reduce* invoking this particular function by **50 percent**.

how do i calculate the estimated performance improvement on the "slow" environment?
**is there any approximate formula for calculating the expected performance gain?**

apologies:
nowadays i'm no longer good at doing any math. or rather i never was!
i have been thinking about where to ask such question, best.
didn't come up with any more suitable place.
also, i wasn't able to come up with an optimal question's subject line and also what tags to assign ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's mostly about math, rather than programming.

Comment: I don't think you provide enough variables to calculate this impact.  If this function is only impacting a 5% of the overall performance, then the impact will be less than if this function impacts 75% of the overall performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make an assumption (questionable but we have nothing else to go on).
Let's assume all of the 5:1 reduction in time is due to function `foo` reducing by 18:1.
That means everything else in the program takes the same amount of time.

So suppose in the fast environment the total time is f + x, where f is the time that `foo` takes in the fast environment, and x is everything else.

In the slow environment, the time is 18f+x, which equals 5(f+x).
OK, solve for x.

18f+x = 5f+5x

13f = 4x

x = 13/4 f

OK, now on the slow environment you want to call `foo` half as much.
So then the time would be 9f+x, which is:

9f + 13/4 f = 49/4 f

The original time was 18f+x = (18+13/4)f = 85/4 f

So the time goes from 85/4 f to 49/4 f.
That's a speed ratio of 85/49 = 1.73

In other words, that's a speedup of 73%.